# Notification Center - How do I know if there is an 'unread' notification?

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

In my app, I have a push notification server working correctly, I receive notifications as expected.

If I am in the app and I receive a notification

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

is called..

If I am outside of the app, and I receive a notification, and click onto it..

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

is called..

If I am outside of the app, receive a notification and load my app by clicking on its icon on the springboard..

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

is **not** called... ?????

I don't understand why this is, surely there is a way to check notification center and say, 'hey! notification center, do I have any unread aps payloads to deal with?'

Comment: Take Whatsapp application for instance, they retrieve user data from the server and check if the user has pending notifications against the server **not** the APNs.

Comment: but that means that you could check with the server and 'receive' the notification, but then go back into notification center, and receive it again.

Comment: The method am trying to explain here is totally independent of the APN service. The notification in the end is just data, so just request that data from the server. This is not a perfect answer, but it may help.

Comment: Yes I understood what you meant, I think my reply was confusing. The APS notifications hold all the data I need, merely a flag to say 'new status on item', having to check the external server every single time I load the app seems unnecessary considering it will (and has in my example) told me I have a new status, if the user reads that flag from the external server once, and then again from the notification center it will +2 to the status, not 1.

Comment: Brilliant!, That's a really simple solution, I should of thought of that myself. Thank you, so i guess the answer to this question is that: No, you cannot query notification center?

Comment: Ah, well .. I haven't used APS .. ever. So, I can't tell for sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of going through all the comments, the conclusion is as follows:

1. Set the Icon badge number
2. Upon launching the application, or return from background, check the app badge.
3. Decide whether to request any data from the server or not.

This is a solution, but we are also interested in:

Can you query the notification center instead?

Comment: heh I too need exactly what you want. But how do you request any data from server. and when you mention server do you mean APN server or any personal server that you maintaining? Please provide some sample code to request any data from the server.

Comment: We are talking about a personal server here. To request data, you need two things: 1- iOS `NSURLConnection` code to download. Search for it, code is abundant. 2- Server side logic that I am not familiar with. Post a new question, hopefully some awesome guy somewhere will know how.